# Incorrect attribute value type Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

While creating an Incident. I am facing this issue. I have created some incidents and it working fine but sometime it shows this exception "Incorrect attribute value type Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue".

How to trace which OptionSetValue throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're creating these via a C# sdk call.  I believe [turning on server side tracing would tell you](http://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com/).  The other option is if you can debug it locally, catch the exception and manually attempt to update each optionset attribute, one at a time until you find the culprit.

Comment: Finally I found how to solve this problem.

When you set an OptionSetValue to a field, you need to check this values exists on the fields. You can check in the Entiry fields view.

Avoid casting a WholeNumber fields type into an OptionSetValue.

Comment: @user1740687 yes, if the user can enter any value they want, and you're converting that to an optionset, you'll need to perform a validation check before updating the entity.